# How to display a colour image using a JPanel?

Tags: java, image-processing

I have a colour image that is been stored in a 3D array and now I want to display this data or the image on to a `JPanel`. My code read function is as follows :

```
public void readImage(String filename) throws Exception {
    String filenameExtension = filename.substring(filename.lastIndexOf('.')+1);
    File fileImage = FileChosen;
    Iterator imageReaders = ImageIO.getImageReadersBySuffix(filenameExtension);

    ImageReader imageReader;

    if(imageReaders.hasNext())
        imageReader = (ImageReader)imageReaders.next();
    else
        throw new IOException("Unsupported image format");

    FileImageInputStream imageInputStream = new FileImageInputStream(fileImage);

    imageReader.setInput(imageInputStream);

    ImgWidth = imageReader.getWidth(0);
    ImgHeight = imageReader.getHeight(0);

    BufferedImage bufImage = imageReader.read(0);
    imageInputStream.close();

    WritableRaster wRaster = bufImage.getRaster();

    //int numBands = wRaster.getNumBands();
            System.out.println(ImgWidth);
            System.out.println(ImgHeight);


    imageArray = (new double[ImgHeight][ImgWidth][ColourLevels]);

    // get the samples and normalize to between 0 and 1
    for(int row = 0; row < ImgHeight; row++)
        for(int col = 0; col < ImgWidth; col++)
            for(int level = 0; level < ColourLevels; level++)
                imageArray[row][col][level] = (wRaster.getSample((col), (row), level) / 255.0);

} // end read method`
```

Now I want to print the data stored in the `imageArray[][][]` in to a panel, how can I do that?

Comment: 1) Create a new image and display it in a `JLabel`. 2) `IOException("Unsupported image format");`  It does not seem like an `IOException` to me.  Perhaps `IllegalArgumentException` would be more appropriate.

Comment: could you please show me the working if possible. Thank you.

Comment: *"show me the working"*  1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) One way to get image(s) for an example is to hot-link to the images seen in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19209651/418556).